Quarkus - MDC context is not shared between app threads
I have 3.8.1 quarkus application. I use org.slf4j.MDC to provide context information. Also I use io.quarkiverse.logging.logback.quarkus-logging-logback extension. I set context info in preMatchingFilter like this:
@ServerRequestFilter(preMatching = true)
public void preMatchingFilter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    MDC.put("X-Request-Id", <SOME-RANDOM-ID>);
}

Everything work fine as long as I run application in intelij (quarkus dev).
But when I run it in docker or k8s env SOME-RANDOM-ID is different in vert.x-eventloop-thread-X (preMatchingFilter) and executor-thread-X (resource method body).
Do you have any idea why this code works fine when run from mvn plugin and why it does not work fine when run in docker env? Docker image base: registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/openjdk-17:1.18
What I tried
I added dependency quarkus-smallrye-context-propagation (https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation) but it didn't work.
I added an implementation of ThreadContextProvider as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/65040601/11420000 but no effect.
Changing MDC to org.jboss.logging.MDC works fine in application but it does not provide X-Request-Id variable to logback.

I tried few new ideas, application run with java -jar behaves similarly to the one run in docker env.
But when I set quarkus.package.type to legacy-jar (https://quarkus.io/guides/class-loading-reference) and run application with java -jar then random-id in preMatching filter is the same as in the resource method body.

slf4j MDC doesn't really work for Quarkus/vertx, since it uses a thread-local variable and processing can change threads in vertx since everything is async. Please read https://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html on how to migrate the context.

@vasquez I do not create threads on my own, as I mentioned I tried solution covered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65039035/manual-context-propagation-in-quarkus-native-mode/65040601#65040601 but it does not work.

To mitigate this you can try and use this library which was written to solve the issue of Vert.x reactor pattern with MDC.
https://reactiverse.io/reactiverse-contextual-logging
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.reactiverse</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactiverse-contextual-logging</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>

